# Creating an Erasor in a PaintApp between 2 Graphics

Tags: c#, forms, paint

In my code there are 2 graphics, the Graphics graphics and the Graphics g. The graphics are used to create the shapes and g is used to move the shapes using the arrow keys.In the code i have an eraser that is used for deleting what ever has been drawn by creating a pen that writes white when the cursor is clicked.With this logic of an eraser i had 0 problems until i intruduced the g graphics for moving the shapes.Now i cant find a way for the erasor to erase on the same graphics as the shape that moved(Notice that after creating a shape it will instantly be drawn in g graphics)the only close solution(which is the one i posted) i have found is this,but the problem is that when ever i click on the form, or i click a button to select a shape to draw what ever the eraser deleted disappears(that means the white color is removed for some reason)

Here i will include the most important parts of the code so you can get a feel of how everything works(The erasor code is in the mousemoves function)

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    startPoint = e.Location;
    draw = true;

    if (addtext)
    {
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox
        {
            Location = pictureBox1.PointToClient(MousePosition),
            Size = new Size(100, 20),
            ForeColor = Color.Black
        };

        textBox.Leave += (s, ev) =>
        {
            TextBox currentTextBox = (TextBox)s;
        };

        pictureBox1.Controls.Add(textBox);
        textBox.Focus();
        addtext = false;
    }

}


private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (draw)
    {
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            width = e.Location.X - startPoint.X;
            height = e.Location.Y - startPoint.Y;
            Rectangle shape = new Rectangle(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, width, height);
            graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, shape);
            graphics.DrawRectangle(eraser, shape);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            draw = false;
        }
        else if (choice == 2)
        {
            width = e.Location.X - startPoint.X;
            height = e.Location.Y - startPoint.Y;
            Rectangle shape = new Rectangle(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, width, height);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, shape);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(eraser, shape);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            draw = false;
        }
        if (draw && choice == 3)
        {
            createPolygon(graphics, pen, startPoint, e.Location, 6);
            createPolygon(graphics, eraser, startPoint, e.Location, 6);
            draw = false;
        }
        else if (choice == 4)
        {
            createPolygon(graphics, pen, startPoint, e.Location, 4);
            createPolygon(graphics, eraser, startPoint, e.Location, 4);
            draw = false;
        }
        else if (choice == 5)
        {
            endPoint = e.Location;
            graphics.DrawLine(pen, startPoint, endPoint);
            graphics.DrawLine(eraser, startPoint, endPoint);
            draw = false;
        }
        else if (choice == 6)
        {
            graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, Math.Abs(e.X - startPoint.X), Math.Abs(e.X - startPoint.X));
            graphics.DrawRectangle(eraser, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, Math.Abs(e.X - startPoint.X), Math.Abs(e.X - startPoint.X));
            draw = false;
        }
        else if (choice == 7)
        {
            graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, e.X - startPoint.X, e.X - startPoint.X);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(eraser, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, e.X - startPoint.X, e.X - startPoint.X);
            draw = false;

        }
        else if (choice == 8)
        {
            Point[] point = { new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y), new Point(startPoint.X, e.Y), new Point(startPoint.X, e.Y) };
            graphics.DrawPolygon(pen, point);
            Point[] point2 = { new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y), new Point(startPoint.X, endPoint.Y), new Point(endPoint.X, endPoint.Y) };
            graphics.DrawPolygon(eraser, point2);
            draw = false;
        }
        else if (choice == 9)
        {
            Point[] point = { new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y), new Point((startPoint.X + e.X) / 2, e.Y), new Point(e.X, startPoint.Y) };
            graphics.DrawPolygon(pen, point);
            graphics.DrawPolygon(eraser, point);
            draw = false;
        }
        else if (choice == 10)
        {
            graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, e.X - startPoint.X, e.X - startPoint.X);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, startPoint.X - 20, startPoint.Y - 20, (e.X - startPoint.X) + 40, (e.X - startPoint.X) + 40);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(eraser, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, e.X - startPoint.X, e.X - startPoint.X);
            graphics.DrawEllipse(eraser, startPoint.X - 20, startPoint.Y - 20, (e.X - startPoint.X) + 40, (e.X - startPoint.X) + 40);
            draw = false; ;
        }
        Shape newShape = new Shape
        {
            Type = choice,
            StartPoint = startPoint,
            EndPoint = endPoint,
            PenColor = pen.Color
        };
        shapes.Add(newShape);

        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
}
private void eraserToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//This is the box that is used for the erasing part
{
    eraserMode = !eraserMode;
    draw = true;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (eraserMode) //Here is the code for the Erasor
    {
        using (Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics())
        {
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.White, 6), startPoint, e.Location);
            startPoint = e.Location;

        }
    }
    if (draw && choice == 1)
    {
        width = e.Location.X - startPoint.X;
        height = e.Location.Y - startPoint.Y;
        graphics.DrawRectangle(eraser, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, endPoint.X - startPoint.X, endPoint.Y - startPoint.Y);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, width, height);
        endPoint = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }


    else if (draw && choice == 2)
    {
        width = e.Location.X - startPoint.X;
        height = e.Location.Y - startPoint.Y;
        graphics.DrawEllipse(eraser, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, endPoint.X - startPoint.X, endPoint.Y - startPoint.Y);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, width, height);
        endPoint = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    else if (draw && choice == 3)
    {
        createPolygon(graphics, eraser, startPoint, endPoint, 6);
        createPolygon(graphics, pen, startPoint, e.Location, 6);
        endPoint = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
    else if (draw && choice == 4)
    {
        createPolygon(graphics, eraser, startPoint, endPoint, 4);
        createPolygon(graphics, pen, startPoint, e.Location, 4);
        endPoint = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();

    }
    else if (draw && choice == 5)
    {
        graphics.DrawLine(eraser, startPoint, endPoint);
        graphics.DrawLine(pen, startPoint, e.Location);
        endPoint = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
    else if (draw && choice == 6)
    {
        graphics.DrawRectangle(eraser, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, endPoint.X - startPoint.X, endPoint.X - startPoint.X);
        graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, e.X - startPoint.X, e.X - startPoint.X);
        endPoint = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    else if (draw && choice == 7)
    {
        graphics.DrawEllipse(eraser, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, endPoint.X - startPoint.X, endPoint.X - startPoint.X);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, e.X - startPoint.X, e.X - startPoint.X);
        endPoint = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
    else if (draw && choice == 8)
    {

        Point[] point2 = { new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y), new Point(startPoint.X, endPoint.Y), new Point(endPoint.X, endPoint.Y) };
        Point[] point = { new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y), new Point(startPoint.X, e.Y), new Point(e.X, e.Y) };
        graphics.DrawPolygon(eraser, point2);
        graphics.DrawPolygon(pen, point);
        endPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y); // Update endPoint here
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
    else if (draw && choice == 9)
    {

        Point[] point4 = { new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y), new Point((startPoint.X + endPoint.X) / 2, endPoint.Y), new Point(endPoint.X, startPoint.Y) };
        Point[] point3 = { new Point(startPoint.X, startPoint.Y), new Point((startPoint.X + e.X) / 2, e.Y), new Point(e.X, startPoint.Y) };
        graphics.DrawPolygon(eraser, point4);
        graphics.DrawPolygon(pen, point3);
        endPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y); // Update endPoint here
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
    else if (draw && choice == 10)
    {


        graphics.DrawEllipse(eraser, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, endPoint.X - startPoint.X, endPoint.X - startPoint.X);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(eraser, startPoint.X - 20, startPoint.Y - 20, (endPoint.X - startPoint.X) + 40, (endPoint.X - startPoint.X) + 40);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, startPoint.X, startPoint.Y, e.X - startPoint.X, e.X - startPoint.X);
        graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, startPoint.X - 20, startPoint.Y - 20, (e.X - startPoint.X) + 40, (e.X - startPoint.X) + 40);
        endPoint = e.Location;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

} //and the code that follows is the code that draws the shapes in the g graphics
private void pictureBox1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var shape in shapes)
    {
        DrawShape(e.Graphics, shape);
    }
}
private void DrawShape(Graphics g, Shape shape)
{

    switch (shape.Type)
    {
        case 1:
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(shape.PenColor, 3), new Rectangle(shape.StartPoint, new Size(shape.EndPoint.X - shape.StartPoint.X, shape.EndPoint.Y - shape.StartPoint.Y)));
            break;
        case 2:
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(shape.PenColor, 3), new Rectangle(shape.StartPoint, new Size(shape.EndPoint.X - shape.StartPoint.X, shape.EndPoint.Y - shape.StartPoint.Y)));
            break;
        case 3:
            // Add logic for drawing hexagon (6-sided polygon)
            createPolygon(g, new Pen(shape.PenColor, 3), shape.StartPoint, shape.EndPoint, 6);
            break;
        case 4:
            // Add logic for drawing square (4-sided polygon)
            createPolygon(g, new Pen(shape.PenColor, 3), shape.StartPoint, shape.EndPoint, 4);
            break;
        case 5:
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(shape.PenColor, 3), shape.StartPoint, shape.EndPoint);
            break;
        case 6:
            g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(shape.PenColor, 3), new Rectangle(shape.StartPoint, new Size(shape.EndPoint.X - shape.StartPoint.X, shape.EndPoint.X - shape.StartPoint.X)));
            break;
        case 7:
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(shape.PenColor, 3), new Rectangle(shape.StartPoint, new Size(shape.EndPoint.X - shape.StartPoint.X, shape.EndPoint.X - shape.StartPoint.X)));
            break;
        case 8:
            createPolygon(g, new Pen(shape.PenColor, 3), shape.StartPoint, shape.EndPoint, 3);
            break;
        case 9:
            createPolygon(g, new Pen(shape.PenColor, 3), shape.StartPoint, shape.EndPoint, 3);
            break;
        case 10:
            // Add logic for drawing concentric circles
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(shape.PenColor, 3), new Rectangle(shape.StartPoint, new Size(shape.EndPoint.X - shape.StartPoint.X, shape.EndPoint.X - shape.StartPoint.X)));
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(shape.PenColor, 3), new Rectangle(new Point(shape.StartPoint.X - 20, shape.StartPoint.Y - 20), new Size(shape.EndPoint.X - shape.StartPoint.X + 40, shape.EndPoint.X - shape.StartPoint.X + 40)));
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your eraser doesn't work permanently because `Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics()` is a TEMPORARY graphics. As soon "pictureBox1" redraws itself, the "erased" parts will re-appear. The easiest way to see this is to erase something, minimize the form, then bring it back up and see that the erased parts return. The "correct" way to do this would be to STORE the information about what parts have been erased in a List, just like you've done with the shapes. Then, in the Paint() event, you'd first draw all the shapes from the list and, AFTERWARDS, draw all the white "erased" parts on top.

Comment: Could someone throw out some code to help me out with the idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a class to hold the two points of your "erased part":

```
public class ErasePoint {

    public Point ptA;
    public Point ptB;

    public ErasePoint(Point a, Point b) {
        ptA = a;
        ptB = b;
    }

}
```

Then you need a List to hold them, declared in the same place as your "shapes" List:

```
List<ErasePoint> erasePoints = new List<ErasePoint>();
```

Now, in your erase code, create an instance of ErasePoint, add it to the List, and `Invalidate()` your PictureBox forcing it to redraw itself:

```
if (eraserMode) //Here is the code for the Erasor
{
    ErasePoint erase = new ErasePoint(startPoint, e.Location);
    erasePoints.Add(erase);
    startPoint = e.Location;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

In the `Paint()` event, draw all the shapes first, then "erase" parts by drawing white on top of that:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Draw all the shapes first
    foreach (var shape in shapes)
    {
        DrawShape(e.Graphics, shape);
    }
    
    // Draw the "erased" parts:
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.White, 6) {
    foreach(ErasePoint ep in erasePoints) {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, ep.ptA, ep.ptB);
    }
}
```

That's the basic idea; completely untested, of course...